# Passing SQL Server exception to .net for ExecuteSprocAccessor to consume

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012, enterprise-library-5

G'Day everybody.
Need the help to finalize the answer to similar question. Unfortunately, since I do not have enough points, I can not ask the final solution for people involved. THe original question is here: "[Passing SQL Server exception to .net][1]"

So,
**PROBLEM:**
TRY/CATCH statement in SQL Server 2012 swallows the exception that I want to pass or re-throw back to EF 5.0. 
As long as the exception is without Try/catch, .NET code gets it without problems.

**Attempts to solve:**
1. FOR SQL SERVER SIDE: We have tried with THROW / RAISEERROR, Raising the exception in and outside of the Try/Catch block, recording the original error and re-throwing it again. 
2. From .NET SIDE tried as planned overloaded "ExecuteSprocAccessor" and changed back to basic code
   "...
     SqlDataAdapter dataadap = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
     dataadap.Fill(dt);
   "
Nothing worked
3. Another option - guess - is to think about some parameter in SQL SERVER that might be blocking it - do not know where to look as yet

**Solution:**
LOOKING for help and advise how the original managed to supressed the TRY/Catch behavior.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have spent another day in further attempt to get to the bottom of it and, accidentally, found temporary solution.
since there is no initial response, I am posting this as a solution. Though, it's more like a temporary solution.
The usage of ***"db.ExecuteDataSet(dbc)"*** worked fine providing the relevant handling of exceptions passed from SQL Server 2012 from Catch block. for us it shows that there are some tricks or problems that we do not know as yet with EL6.0 and/or ADO.NET in new version

```html
    *using ( DbCommand dbc = db.GetStoredProcCommand("[Personnel].[uspWebLogin]"))
            {
                db.AddInParameter(dbc, "UserLogin", DbType.String, user.UserLogin);
                db.AddInParameter(dbc, "UserPassword", DbType.String, user.Password);
                DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbc);
                DataTableReader dtr =  ds.CreateDataReader();
                
    // string count just to check theat the core query actualy worked when there is no exception
    string count = dtr.FieldCount.ToString();
    ......
                return new WebUser();
            }*
```

The problems are now on how to optimize the best mapping of objects and return set instead of writing heaps of code which "ExecuteSprocAccessor" and "IRowMapper" were doing for us.

Thanks for reading. Any further comments or suggestions are still welcomed. Cheers.